# How long can a refrigerator be stored without being used?

Tags: refrigerator

I purchased a refrigerator 8 months ago, but it will not be used right away. It came directly from the showroom. Must I use it now, or I can wait longer before using it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you use a refrigerator which cannot be used? Can you wait more than 8 months for what?

Comment: If it was used and not sanitized before storage and not kept with the door cracked opened: about a month and then the whole thing is hazardous waste. Unused? Until too much refrigerant leaks out, which should be +20 years.

Answer (score 4):

Clean empty refrigerators should be stored upright and kept dry. You should prevent moisture building up inside the stored refrigerator - perhaps by removing the door or by keeping the door open.

The manufacturer's instruction booklet may have a section on storage.

Unused refrigerators are a potentially fatal hazard for children, who may get trapped inside. For this reason doors should be removed, locked closed or prevented from being closed (using a child-proof mechanism).

Comment: These are good practices, but regarding his concern of whether it can be stored and still be good, I add the following: Refrigeration systems are "sealed" system, use oil-less compressors in most cases, and there are no specific "lifespans" for the refrigerant. This means that, provided you follow the storage practices mentioned by @RedGrittyBrick and store in a location that will not promote rusting, it should be fine to store until you are ready to use it. I recommend a good cleaning before turning it on, with compressed air, just to avoid working additional dust working into the move parts.

Comment: Is the thinking that `Unused refrigerators are a potentially fatal hazard for children, who may get trapped inside` dated? This seems like it would apply to fridges which have a mechanical latch like you'd see in the 50s. Fridges these days are sealed with magnets that aren't all that strong. Maybe a kid could get trapped but they could also push their way out unlike a latched door where it is physically impossible to push your way out.

Comment: @Brad: You are right but child suffocation deaths, though probably very rare, [still happen](https://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/3926649). As this answer may be seen by people with old or defective fridges, it doesn't hurt to leave that paragraph there.

Answer (score 3):

If your refrigerator was stored upright, then plug it in and see if it works.  Plugging it in isn't going to harm it.  And if there is something wrong with it you will need to turn it on to diagnose.

If your refrigerator was stored any other way find the manufacturer's guidelines on how long it needs to be upright.  This may range between 15 mins to 1 day.  If you can't figure out the manufacturer or make and model then leave it upright for a day before using.  It would generally be good practice to cleaning it before turning it on too.

Answer (score 0):

I have stored a refrigerator for several years and had no problems with it working when I needed it. I believe you should be OK.