# How long can a new fridge in original packaging be stored?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, electronics

I have a new fridge, and I haven't even opened the packaging. For how long can it be stored as it is, without causing damage? It's my second fridge and I don't need this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long can a refrigerator be stored without being used?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28773/how-long-can-a-refrigerator-be-stored-without-being-used)

Comment: You'd probably do better selling the second one and using the proceeds to regularly service the existing one.

Answer (score 7):

It should keep for years but you should start it up to make sure it's working correctly because of the warranty. Store it upright but if laying it down, let it set for 24 hours upright before starting. Store in a dry place to prevent any rusting.

Comment: To do a full functional test, you would need to open the packing before starting it up for proper ventilation for the compressor(s) and to defrost it properly after the test. Otherwise you risk damaging the fridge running it for an extended period while all packaged up and/or coating the inside with mold by not defrosting properly.

Comment: @statueuphemism  I kinda thought that was a given but considering this is a DIY site, it's a great point to bring up.. thanks

Comment: The question looked to be asking about how long can they leave it still packaged is why I brought it up as a clarification just in case.